# Ubuntu 11.10 and Mobility radeon HD 4570, 512MB can't find working drivers

Tags: drivers, ati, radeon

i'm pretty new to Linux and my new problem is ATI drivers. When i installed Ubuntu then i had black screen issue with the blinking in left upper corner, fixed it with F6 and set the "nolapic" mode, can boot only with "nolapic". Now the problem is the drivers. The suggested drivers, from the "Additional drivers" are not working. Always freeze at the login screen, the divers are:

ATI/AMD proprietary FGLRX graphics driver

Tried this method: http://drivers.downloadatoz.com/tutorial/28786,how-to-fix-amd-catalyst-11-10-not-working-on-ubuntu-11-10-issues.html?

but this method break it down really hard, not ever that helped anymore:

```
sudo /usr/share/ati/fglrx-uninstall.sh  # (if it exists);
sudo apt-get remove --purge fglrx*;
sudo apt-get remove --purge xserver-xorg-video-ati xserver-xorg-video-radeon ;
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-ati;
sudo apt-get install --reinstall libgl1-mesa-glx libgl1-mesa-dri xserver-xorg-core;
sudo dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg
```

Now i'm here with a fresh install and i cant find anything that works, can someone help me please! I like Ubuntu, but i need to get rid of the lagg, or its Windows 7 only for me then :(

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 3):

your graphics card seems to be listed user the legacy drivers list in the Radeon HD 4X series. Please download the driver from this link: http://support.amd.com/us/kbarticles/Pages/catalyst126legacyproducts.aspx

Before installing, remove the fglrx drivers you installed from the ubuntu software centre. See if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

For me I just installed the proprietary drivers via the Ubuntu system settings panel. It was pretty easy but after it was installed it said it was not in use but it really was there is a quick easy way to check. [Proprietary Drivers for Ubuntu](http://ubuntuforum.webs.com/proprietarydrivers.htm)